# How to create a button with Hyperlink in Streamlit?

Tags: python, button, hyperlink, streamlit

I would like to create a button with a Hyperlink in `Streamlit`. I thought maybe using `st.button` with this syntax: `[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com)`. But unfortunately this has no success, it only displays the text and doesn't make it as a hyperlink. I found [this](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-component-link-button-a-simple-way-to-link-a-button-to-a-url/16824) workaround, but this doesn't work anymore. I don't want to use `st.markdown` with a hyperlink because that doesn't create a button. Here is a reproducible example:

```
"""
# Streamlit app
"""

import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Button with hyperlink
st.button('[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com)')
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't create a hyperlink. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a button with a hyperlink in Streamlit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use markdown, `a` and `button` tags.

```
import streamlit as st

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

st.markdown(f'''
<a href={url}><button style="background-color:GreenYellow;">Stackoverflow</button></a>
''',
unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example styled a bit more like streamlit:

```py
def redirect_button(url: str, text: str= None, color="#FD504D"):
    st.markdown(
    f"""
    <a href="{url}" target="_self">
        <div style="
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: {color};
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-decoration: none;">
            {text}
        </div>
    </a>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True
    )
redirect_button("http://stackoverflow.com","this leads to SO")
```

[image]

Comment: Streamlit have their own proper link button now, don't use this as it is probably less secure that builtins

Answer (score 1):

You can use `st.link_button()`

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.link_button

```
import streamlit as st

st.link_button("Go to gallery", "https://streamlit.io/gallery")
```